# Store Associative Array values into comma-separated string

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array and I can store its values comma-separated, in a string.

Associative Array has `keys`/`values`

```
0 => 1
1 => 3
```

I have tried this

```
$selected_sizes_comma_seprated = "";
foreach ($selected_sizes as $size) {
    $selected_sizes_comma_seprated .= $size.',';
}
// Remove last comma in string
$selected_sizes_comma_seprated = substr($selected_sizes_comma_seprated, 0,-1);
```

This works fine as I want.

My question is that is there any other better solution to achieve this

Comment: Yeah, look at [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**implode()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) does just that:

```
$selected_sizes = array(0 => 1, 1 => 3);

$selected_sizes_comma_seprated = implode(',', $selected_sizes);

echo $selected_sizes_comma_seprated; // 1,3
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/c6qq1jZo)

Comment: @UmairAyub if this did indeed helped you, kindly accept/upvote this answer

Answer (score 0):

use [join()](http://php.net/function.join) or [impode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) is alias

like

```
$selected_sizes_comma_seprated = join(',', $selected_sizes);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has it own function to generate CSV file `fputcsv()`

```
<?php

$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

For more reference http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php